# add data to a modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm working with modal dialog, can i put data from a form on the modal dialog? like textbox value, or dropdown list value? how can i do that?

modal dialog code:

```
var isConfirmed = false;
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var dialog = $("#dialog");
    if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
        dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"> Los datos ingresados son:</div>').appendTo('body');
    }
    dialog.load(

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            close: function(event, ui) {
                dialog.remove();
            },
            resizable: false,
            //height: 140,
            //width: 460
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    isConfirmed = true;
                    $("form").submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        })
    );
    if (isConfirmed)
        return true;
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe there's something I miss but...add data to your dialog controls as they're _normal_ controls outside the dialog (val() method, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same procedure you're currently using to append the dialog to the page. You're using this:

```
dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:none"> Los datos ingresados son:</div>').appendTo('body');
```

(Note: you were using `display:hidden`, which is invalid. Changed to `display:none` above.)

Similarly, you can do this:

```
$('<div id="dialog_content">Whatever you want inside the dialog</div>').appendTo(dialog);
```

Comment: thanks man!, it really helps! how can i add some variables like $("#textbox") or ("#dropdown") to that?

Comment: $('<div id="dialog_content">División:' + $("#division").val() + '</div>').appendTo(dialog);

this works, thanks

Comment: Yes, that's it, you need `.val()` to extract values from form fields.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
dialog.data('yourDataKey', 'yourData')
```

and change your check if the dialog exists to

```
if (dialog.length == 0) {
    dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"> Los datos ingresados son:</div>').appendTo('body');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the dialog method is attached to an element of some sort - typically a div - you can place anything that you want in that div. Here is an example from the docs:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

The paragraph is in the div that is bound to the method.